# Python: How to tell Socket when to stop receiving data?

Tags: python, loops, sockets, pickle

**The Bug**
When im running the functions as seen below WITH the assert in send() everything works as expected an the code doesnt stop at the socket.recv but gets into the break condition.

HOWEVER

When i remove the assert statement in the send() function, the socket.recv() gets all data completly, but never enters the break condition. E.g. it stops at the recv and never exits the loop.

How can this happen? Why does the assert AFTER the send affect this? How can i reliably send strings?

**Send**

```
def send_model(socket, state_dict):
   """Sends a PyTorch model state_dict over a network socket."""

   # Serialize the state_dict to a byte string
   serialized = pickle.dumps(state_dict)

   # Send the serialized state_dict
   socket.send(serialized)

   assert 0 == 1 ###THIS ASSSERT HERE###
```

**Receive**

```
def recv_model(socket):

data = b''
while True:
    print("before")
    chunk = socket.recv(10000)
    print(chunk)
    if not chunk: 
        break
    data += chunk

state_dict = pickle.loads(data)
# Deserialize the state_dict from the serialized byte string

return state_dict
```

Comment: When the other connection to the socket is closed, you can still send data since the socket itself is still open, but the client disconnected. To handle this, you can either send packet telling the other side has disconnected or maybe trying to assert the `recv()`

Answer (score 0):

The assert statement will cause your sender to exit, which also implicitly closes the socket to the receiver. Without the sender closing the socket your receiver will not know that no more data are coming, i.e. it will wait in `recv` for more data.

If you want the receiver to know when your data end without closing the socket then you could send the size of the data up-front in a fixed size prefix to the data. In this case the receiver will read the prefix, determine the size and only read as much bytes as the message is supposed to be.

Note that your code is also broken in other ways: you expect `send` to send all data, but it might send only parts of it. Use `sendall` to make sure to send all.

Comment: So the only way to reliably close the socket is to send the byte length upfront? Or how else can you close it?

Comment: Also why does it work when i put the assert statement there?

Comment: You can explicitly call `socket.close()` when there is no more data to be sent.

Comment: @typo You don't have a reproducible example but the `assert` throws an exception that in the stack cleanup must either close the socket or just exit the process (also closing the socket).

Comment: @Typo: *"Also why does it work when i put the assert statement there?"* - to cite my answer *"The assert statement will cause your sender to exit, which also implicitly closes the socket to the receiver. "*.  *"So the only way to reliably close the socket is to send the byte length upfront?"* - if you want to close the socket after each message just explicitly call `socket.close()`. The length is for the case (to cite again): *"...you want the receiver to know when your data end without closing the socket"*.

Comment: more specifically i want to keep the socket open, but i want the function to know when to stop calling recv()

Comment: @Typo: and for this you need to know when the data ends. And for this you need to know the size of the data (or have some special character at the end which never occurs in the data). And to know the size you need to send the size before the message - as I suggested in my answer. Note that TCP has no inherent concept of messages but is just a byte stream. Any message semantics need to be implemented at the application level.

Answer (score 0):

`socket.recv` only returns when the socket closes (receives 0 bytes), or at least 1 byte has been received.  If the socket is open but no data is available, it will block.

One advantage of `pickle` is that its protocol can read multiple pickled objects from a file-like stream, so wrap the socket in a file-like object via `socket.makefile` and read the objects until end-of-file occurs (the socket is closed).

`socket.send` can also return early without sending all the data.  This can occur, for example, when intermediate network buffers are full due to the receiver reading too slowly.  Use `socket.sendall` to ensure all data is sent.

Below is a simple client/server example that sends multiple pickled objects.  Call `pickle.load(rfile)` to receive a complete message each time.  You won't have to worry about message size since the pickle protocol handles it.

srv.py

```py
import socket
import pickle

with socket.socket() as s:
    s.bind(('', 5000))
    s.listen()
    while True:
        c, a = s.accept()
        print(f'{a}: connected')
        # with will close the client socket and makefile wrapper when exited.
        with c, c.makefile('rb') as rfile:
            while True:
                try:
                    data = pickle.load(rfile)
                except EOFError: # when socket closes
                    break
                print(f'{a}: {data}')
        print(f'{a}: disconnected')
```

client.py

```py
import socket
import pickle

with socket.socket() as s:
    s.connect(('localhost', 5000))
    s.sendall(pickle.dumps([1,2,3]))
    s.sendall(pickle.dumps({'key': 'value'}))
    s.sendall(pickle.dumps([{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}, 4, 5]))
```

Start server, then run client a few times.

Server output after 3 runs of client:

```
('127.0.0.1', 22995): connected
('127.0.0.1', 22995): [1, 2, 3]
('127.0.0.1', 22995): {'key': 'value'}
('127.0.0.1', 22995): [{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}, 4, 5]
('127.0.0.1', 22995): disconnected
('127.0.0.1', 22996): connected
('127.0.0.1', 22996): [1, 2, 3]
('127.0.0.1', 22996): {'key': 'value'}
('127.0.0.1', 22996): [{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}, 4, 5]
('127.0.0.1', 22996): disconnected
('127.0.0.1', 22999): connected
('127.0.0.1', 22999): [1, 2, 3]
('127.0.0.1', 22999): {'key': 'value'}
('127.0.0.1', 22999): [{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}, 4, 5]
('127.0.0.1', 22999): disconnected
```

Comment: `send()` will only behave as you describe if the socket is in non-blocking mode. Otherwise the only way `send()` can return early is if EINTR occurred.

Comment: @user207421 Not according to the [Python Socket Programming HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html#socket-programming-howto). So is what you say true for all versions of python on all OSes? Then submit a documentation change.