# pickle.loads(clientSocket.recv(4028)) stuck

Tags: python, sockets, server, tcp, network-programming

I am running a server and a client. The client request to sign up and must enter a username. After this point the program gets stuck in the line `message = pickle.loads(clientSocket.recv(4028))`on the server side.

**client**

```
from socket import *
import account
import message
import pickle
import sys

myAccount = account.Account(accUsername="spaceHolder", status=account.Status.OFFLINE)
serverName = "196.47.231.19"
serverPort = 15020
clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
clientSocket.connect((serverName, serverPort))

def signUp():
    while True:
        global myAccount
        userName = input("Please enter a user name you like or q to quit\n").strip()
        messageToSend = message.Message(userName) #sent messageToSend.text = usernName
        if userName == "q":
            break
        clientSocket.sendall(pickle.dumps(message.Message("SignUp*******"))) #1st message sent this messge is recieved in the main method on the server (used to identify the request i.e SignUp from SignIn for example)
        clientSocket.sendall(pickle.dumps(messageToSend)) #2nd message sent
        createdAcc = (pickle.loads(clientSocket.recv(4028))).account #3rd message recieved
        if(createdAcc.status == account.Status.OFFLINE):
            print("That username is taken\n")
        else:
            myAccount = createdAcc
            print("Account created your username is:\n"+myAccount.accUsername)
            break

def main():
    while True:
    
        #Sign Up
        if(myAccount.status == account.Status.OFFLINE):
            request = input("1. Sign Up\n")
            if request == "1":
                signUp()
            else:
                print("Enter valid option")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**server**

```
from socket import *
import pickle
import threading
import account
import message


userBase = []
userBaseLock = threading.Lock()

requests = ["SignUp*******"]


def alreadyAUser(userName) -> bool:
    result = False
    for currentUser in userBase:
        if(currentUser.accUsername == userName):
            result = True
            break
    return result

def getAccount(userName) -> account.Account:
    result = account.Account()
    for currentUser in userBase:
        if(currentUser.accUsername == userName):
            result = currentUser
    return result

def updateUserBase(userToUpdate):
    for currentUser in userBase:
        if (currentUser.accUsername == userToUpdate.accUsername):
            currentUser.status = userToUpdate.status
            currentUser.inbox = userToUpdate.inbox
            currentUser.address = userToUpdate.address
            currentUser.port = userToUpdate.port
            break
        
def signUp(clientSocket):
    print("Top") #debug
    username = pickle.loads(clientSocket.recv(4028)).text #2nd Message recieved. This is where it gets stuck. specifically clientSocket.recv(4028) does not end evaluating
    print("Buttom") #debug
    if(not alreadyAUser(username)):
        user = account.Account()
        user.accUsername = username
        user.status = account.Status.ONLINE
        with userBaseLock:
            userBase.append(user)
        messageToSend = message.Message().withAccount(user)
        clientSocket.sendall(pickle.dumps(messageToSend)) #3rd Message sent
    else:
        clientSocket.sendall(pickle.dumps(message.Message().withAccount(account.Account()))) #3rd Message Sent


def clientHandler(clientSocket):
    while True:
        messageSent = pickle.loads(clientSocket.recv(4028)) #1st message recieved
        message = messageSent.text

        # Sign Up
        if (message == requests[0]): #request[0] = "SignUp*******"
            signUp(clientSocket)
            

def main():
    postNumber = 15020
    serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    serverSocket.bind(('',postNumber))
    serverSocket.listen(1)

    while True:
        clientSocket, clientAddr = serverSocket.accept()
        clientHandlerThread = threading.Thread(target=clientHandler, args=(clientSocket,))
        clientHandlerThread.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**account**

```
import enum

class Status(enum.Enum):
    OFFLINE = "Offline"
    ONLINE = "Online"
    AWAY = "Away"

class Account:
    def __init__(self, accUsername="spaceHolder", status=Status.OFFLINE, address="", port=-1):
        self.accUsername = accUsername
        self.inbox = {}
        self.status = status
        self.address = address
        self.port = port
```

**message**

```
import account

class Message:
    def __init__(self, text="spaceHolder", account=None, ipAddress="spaceHolder", portNumber=-1):
        self.text = text
        self.account = account
        self.ipAddress = ipAddress
        self.portNumber = portNumber

    def withAccount(self, account):
        self.account=account
        return self
```

When you want to reproduce the error you must run the server.py program and then the client program. Then you must input 1 inorder to sign up then type in any thing (username). The program will just stop (no error given). Its gets stuck right after it enters the signUp function on the server.

Comment: Make a [mcve] so we can copy, paste, and run to reproduce your issue with *no changes*

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/76185606/235698

Comment: 4028 is a strange number. Where did that come from? Do you mean 2048? But the problem here is that the server will probably receive both the client's first two messages in the first `recv()`. You are relying on a 1-1 correspondence between `send()` and `recv()` that doesn't exist. You need to ponder on this.

Comment: Can you share the code where the sockets are created and configured?

Comment: @BillHorvath Why? If he wasn't calling `socket(), bind(), listen(),` and `accept()`, *with correct parameters,* he couldn't have obtained `clientSocket`, wouldn't have succeed in the first `recv()`, and wouldn't be blocked in the second `recv()`. What is it you' re looking for? TCP streaming is already a sufficient explanation.

Comment: @user207421 yes i was relaying on one to one correspondece between send and recv. I changed the code so that it uses 2048. Sometimes if works though (i.e correctly signs up the user).

Comment: @MarkTolonen I mananged to provide the full code. The error is reproducible but please note that it might work for the first 2 or 3 times. If it works just close both programs and try again. If nothing is printed out after you type in the username then the program is stuck on the sgnUp function from the server side.

Comment: Instead of sending two messages and expecting them to be received as two messages, send them as *one* message and decode them properly at the receiver. I would have thought that `pickle` could already cope with that.